# glycine hydrochloride salt how I can get it

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, amino-acids

I do not understand what Glycine•HCl salt is (concretely). Is it a mix between glycine and HCl salt (I don't know if HCl salt is existing...) or something else ?

I understand that glycine is an amino acid and in solution glycine HCl is like the following picture

[image]

But what happens when the solvent evaporate? What is the meaning of the point • between Glycine and HCl ?

Comment: Glycine•HCl salt is an ionic salt, much like NaCl. It is one single compound and not a mix of any sort.

Comment: When the solvent evaporates you are left with solid glycine hydrochloride

Comment: Thank you for your both answers. I think it's cear now. It was strange to figure HCl like salt... Thx

Comment: Just a comment on nomenclature. The nature of glycine hydrochloride would be much clearer if its more systematic name (and according to the real contents of the salt), glycinium chloride, was used.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the dot in the formula indicates some kind of association compound; the prime examples of such dots are crystal hydrates such as $\ce{CuSO4 . 5 H2O}$. In that, five molecules of water are present for each pair of copper(II) and sulphate ions.

In organic chemistry, these dots are usually used in a somewhat misleading way including the somewhat nonintuitive description as a ‘hydrochloride salt’. What this means is that the most basic position of the molecule is protonated and this cation forms a salt with a chloride anion. The effect is equivalent to adding hydrochloric acid to a solution of the molecule and then removing the solvent. In glycine’s case, while the compound is often called glycine hydrochloride salt its systematic name would be glycinium chloride; indicating both the fact that the proton is somewhere on the glycine molecule (where depends on the original solvent) and an additional chloride ion forms a salt with this cation.